# How to split an observable into two per-field observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable for querying parameters with a nested/inner observable for querying a service call. I know that the result object has two fields: `id :string` and `complexValue :Complex`.

```typescript
this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
        let myParameter = params.get('myParameter')!;
        return this.myService.getComplex(myParameter);
      })
);
```

Now I would like to make two observables out of this observable - one per field.

My goal is to be able to use two fields called `id$: Observable<string>` and `complexValue$: Observable<Complex>` in the angular template.

How can I archive this?

Comment: const id = routeObservable.pipe(map(val => val.id));
const complexValue = routeObservable.pipe(map(val => val.complexValue)) where routeObservable is the entire code you've pasted. Since you want them in template, I'd suggest making them class level properties instead of local variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can share the source Observable and then just use two `pluck()`s (or you could use `map()`s as well):

```
const source$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
  switchMap((params: ParamMap) => {
    let myParameter = params.get('myParameter')!;
    return this.myService.getComplex(myParameter);
  }),
  share(),
);

const complexValue$ = source$.pipe(pluck('complexValue'));
const id$ = source$.pipe(pluck('id'));
```